# Программное изменение положения ползунка SeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-handler, seekbar

Имеется следующий код метода:

```
private int secs = 0;
private void onPlayClick(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                double percent = (double) secs/SONG_LENGTH;
                int progress =(int) (percent*100);
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                secs++;
        }
    };
    for (int i = seekBar.getProgress()*SONG_LENGTH/100; i<=SONG_LENGTH;i++) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000*i);
    }
}
```

Его задача - постепенно изменять положение ползунка `SeekBar`. Однако почему-то вместо постепенного перемещения происходит мгновенное перемещение его в конец `SeekBar`. В чем проблема?

Comment: лучше не переписывать вопрос, а добавлять данные, чтобы можно было проследить логику самого вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически, у вас написано: "запостить результат через 1 секунду Х раз".

То есть весь ваш код резолвится в один момент (через 1 секунду). Введите для 1000 в `handler.postDelayed()` множитель, в зависимости от итерации цикла, и всё должно заработать.

**upd:** Лучше сделать как-то так:

```
secs = 0; //глобальная переменная
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {                 
        seekBar.setProgress(secs);
        secs++;
    }
};

for(int i=0;i<SONG_LENGTH/100;i++)            
    new Handler().postDelayed(runnable,1000*i);
```

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. PostDelayed() же осуществляет паузу потока на (в данном случае) 1000 мс на каждой итерации, нет?

Comment: нет, он не осуществляет паузу потока. Он лишь откладывает "post" на 1 секунду. В соответствии с вашим кодом - X раз.

Comment: Вообще, лучше вынести цикл из потока и прописать его в `postDelayed`

Comment: Этот момент понял, но о каком множителе идет речь? Попробовал к примеру на `secs`  домножать - не помогло

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii , посмотрите, обновил ответ.

Comment: Сделал так как вы посоветовали, заработало, но теперь почему-то меняется в некоторых местах сразу на 2 секунды, а в некоторых наоборот ждет 2 секунды, но изменяет значение на 1. Из-за чего это может быть? Обновил вопрос.

Comment: у вас `i` в цикле изначально должно равняться 0. И посмотрите, я убрал из кода всё лишнее. У меня работает корректно